# Eclipse showing error for an android application in 'Package Explorer', but no error found anywhere in the code

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an android application using Eclipse IDE. Eclipse is showing error icon on the android application, but I can't find any error anywhere inside the sub folders(sections). Because of this error, I can't run or debug the application. When I try to run or debug, "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application" error window is appearing.

Why can't I find any error inside my android application ? How can I fix this issue ?

---

UPDATE :

I found a problem. The R.java file is now missing. How this happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens most of the time for me. For me it was due to giving same ID to different TextViews, ListViews, GridViews or other type of user controls that are used in different XML files. You too will be having this issue. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely because the error is not in your code but on the project setup. Try to open the Log View by clicking `Window > Show View > Error Log`:

[image: example]

Then you might want to fix it by opening your project preferences.

Comment: The error log is not opening.